# Add pointerenter and pointerleave event listeners to map / container?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have many shapes in a group, and need to listen to `pointerenter` and `pointerleave` events for them. Currently I am adding the event listeners to each of the shapes, but as I understand it, it is better to have a single listener covering all of them.

Following the example here to add an event listener for `tap`: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/events/map-objects-event-delegation, I want to do the same but for `pointerenter` and `pointerleave`, but no matter how I try I can't get either of them to fire.

I have tried adding it to the `container`, as in the example above:

```
container.addEventListener('pointerenter', function(event){
   console.log(event.target);
});
```

And also to the `map`:

```
map.addEventListener('pointerenter', function(event){
   console.log(event.target);
});
```

The `tap` event fires perfectly fine, but for `pointerenter` and `pointerleave` I am currently forced to add the two listeners to each individual shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current snippet, the pointerenter event is triggered but only when the mouse enters the top-level object, map or container.

However you can achieve what you're looking for if you use the third, optional, parameter of the `addEventListener` function, and set it to true so as the indicate that the handler should listen during the *capture* phase, as opposed to the *bubbling* phase:

```
map.addEventListener('pointerenter', function (event) {
  console.log(event.target instanceof H.geo.Polygon);
}, true);
```

[addEventListener API reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-util-eventtarget.html#h-util-eventtarget__addeventlistener)